# My rooted samsung galaxy s4 is soft bricked, Can I save it?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, unbricking

The device has been rooted since shortly after I bought it new years ago. I've had very few problems since... which is why it's never been replaced.

When I start the device it gets stuck at the splash screen with the sprint logo.

I can get the device to "download mode" but I don't know what to do once there and I'm not sure I can do anything from here.

I can get the device to "android system recovery."
I've wiped the "cache partition" but the problem remained.
I'm not sure what else to do from here.

I'm trying to salvage the data on the internal storage. 
I'm pretty sure I could successfully "wipe data/ factory reset" and get it to "function" again but that's not the priority.
I'm going to replace it regardless of success or failure.
Data recovery is the priority here. (pictures and videos of my young children as well as less important stuff.)

I have an old laptop with an old version of ubuntu I can use or a newer one with windows 7 to work with. I mention this in case it makes this easier to help?

Thank you very much if you try to take a stab at this or refer someone that might!

Comment: I cannot really answer that. But as you don't know what to do in download mode (which is most likely where your solution lies), take a look at our [odin tag wiki](/tags/odin/info) – as that's what download mode is for (Odin operations).

Comment: And after you've looked at that tag wiki, you need to flash a custom recovery (TWRP) from where you'll be able to backup your `/data` partition (the one wiped during a factory reset). If your phone supports an external SD card, I also suggest copying the contents of the internal storage to said card.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks I managed to figure that out last night and used Odin to reinstall TWRP.  I did have it at one point.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I managed to figure that much out, see my comment from a second ago.  The problem I'm running into now is that my data partition and internal storage can't be mounted because they're encrypted. I'm using the latest version of TWRP 3.1.x but it doesn't offer me the option to enter a password.  It just won't allow access to the partition.